# What type of padding do I need to use in Android studio to center my buttons on the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to adjust the home screen on my app to move the buttons slightly to the right.

Here's a link to an image version of my current home screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSDGJ.jpg]

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c1pV.jpg]

All the icons I uploaded have extra room on them to adjust for the padding.I made the icons on sketch and uploaded them as entire buttons.
Here's a screenshot of one of them:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/GuqjjLW]

I know I need to do something with padding, but what should I write to ensure that icons and text are shifted to the right.

Here's the activity in question:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_learn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/learn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/learn_layer_long"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/learn"
        android:textSize="22sp"
       />





</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_find_care"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/find_care_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding = "0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/findcare_layer_long"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/learn"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_talk_to_doctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/TalkToADocButton"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/talk_doc_layer_long"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_visit_website"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/VisitWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:src="@mipmap/visit_web_layer_long"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to look into using a ConstraintLayout instead. Centering items and adding weights to them are so much easier.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is via constraint layout. It's responsive and will handle all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_learn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/findcare_layer_long"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@android:string/untitled"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_find_care"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/findcare_layer_long"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@android:string/untitled"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_talk_to_doctor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/talk_doc_layer_long"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@android:string/untitled"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_visit_website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/visit_web_layer_long"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@android:string/untitled"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This did not work because these are all image buttons, not images.

Comment: But your click can be on `LinearLayout`, it haven't difference

Answer (score 0):

Set your padding within your parent layout. So if you want a padding for all of your 4 sides of **"5dp"**, you will do the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus.MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have customized your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_learn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/learn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_ico"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:text="learn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_find_care"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/find_care"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_ico"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:text="Find Care"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_talk_to_doctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TalkToADocButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_ico"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:text="Emergency"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_visit_website"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/VisitWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_ico"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:text="Message to a Doctor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** Change colors and icons as per your requirements. Because here I have used sample image and colors for testing purpose.

**Output:**

[image: Layout]